# WebSite Loading time

Tags: image, compression, pageload

I'm developing a site which has a slider on home page.I'm using nivo slider.
The images in the slider are of sizes 1600*1200.Due to this the home page is taking too much time to load.

Is there a way so that the images sizes are reduced on the fly or I've to first compress each image and then upload it to the server.

Is there any other alternative method, please suggest one if any.

Comment: Do you want to show lower resolution images? Do you want to asynchronously load the images? Do you want the 1st image to load before the others? What do you mean by 'on the fly'?

Comment: No i dont want to show low resolution images.I want to load all images in one queue itself as I'm using a slider.By on the fly I mean using jquery before DOM is ready

Comment: How many 1600x1200 images are you talking about? Are you asking how to speed up the internet?

Comment: there are in all 10 images in the slider, my question is the browser takes too much amount of time to load these heavy images. So what is the way wherein the images would be loaded faster.Do I've to compress them through yahoo smush it or is there any alternate way through jquery or css

Comment: ok finally got it do not use window.load function, instead just define a function and initialize( call ) the slider...this would load only the first image and would not wait until all others are to be loaded

Comment: Oh good, I'll re-post that as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can load the images asynchronously with help of jQuery. Here is the [tutorial for loading images in nivoslider asynchronised](http://www.webgalli.com/blog/beautiful-jquery-home-page-slideshow-with-translations/). This will reduce the page load time tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the 1st image before the others, which is enough to show the slider. Afterward, you can asynchronously load the other images.